# How do I programmatically refer to a breakpoint in WinDbg?

Tags: windbg

### Programmatic Breakpoint IDs

[Breakpoint Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/breakpoint-syntax#breakpoints-in-scripts) (learn.microsoft.com) claims this about setting breakpoints using an expression for the ID.

> Breakpoint IDs do not have to be referred to explicitly. Instead, you
>   can use a numerical expression that resolves to an integer that
>   corresponds to a breakpoint ID. To indicate that the expression should
>   be interpreted as a breakpoint, use the following syntax.
>
> `b?[Expression]`
>
> In this syntax, the square brackets are required, and Expression stands for any numerical expression that resolves to an integer that corresponds to a breakpoint ID.

This is exactly what I want to do. However, it doesn't seem to work for me.
The one example they give

> `b?[@$t0]`

produces a syntax error. I tried it a few other ways.

```
0:000> r $t0 = 300
0:000> ? $t0
Evaluate expression: 768 = 00000300
0:000> b?[@$t0]
        ^ Syntax error in 'b?[@$t0]'
0:000> b0
        ^ Syntax error in 'b0'
0:000> b
        ^ Syntax error in 'b'
0:000> bl?[@$t0]
        ^ Syntax error in 'bl?[@$t0]'
0:000> bl
 0 e 77c27d89     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b
0:000> bl0
 0 e 77c27d89     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b
0:000> bl300
0:000>
```

I don't really know if the example given is viable, since `b` and `b0` don't work. However, I can't seem to use a similar syntax for commands that otherwise work with hardcoded values.

How can I make use of this (mythical?) feature?

*(WinDbg 10.0.17134.12 X86)*

Comment: It looks like you're in the windbg command window and not in script. In such case you should use bu/bp commands (as stated in the link you referenced)

Comment: What's the difference between the window and a script? The syntax is the same, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The what is a regex substitute either of these (p,u,a)  which will denote 
bp1 .. bpn  | ba1 ... ban | bu1 .. bun

```
0:000> bl
 0 e 62e5f7a0     0001 (0001)  xxx
 1 e 62e5f7a2     0001 (0001)  xxx
 2 e 62e5f7a3     0001 (0001)  xxx
 3 e 62e5f7a5     0001 (0001)  xxx

0:000> bp[8-5]
breakpoint 3 exists, redefining
breakpoint 0 redefined
0:000>
```

or a better usage scenerio

```
0:000> bp .
0:000> bl
 0 e 77ac05a6     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c
0:000> r $t0 =0
0:000> bp[@$t0] ntdll!LdrpCompareServiceChecksum
breakpoint 0 exists, redefining
0:000> bl
 0 e 77a4b931     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!LdrpCompareServiceChecksum
0:000> bp[@$t0] kernel32!CreateWaitableTimerExA
breakpoint 0 exists, redefining
0:000> bl
 0 e 77584202     0001 (0001)  0:**** kernel32!CreateWaitableTimerExA
0:000>
```